# Multi-threading with core data and API requests

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data

**Intro**

I've read alot of tutorials and articles on Core Data concurrency, but I'm having an issue that is not often covered, or covered in a real-world way that I am hoping someone can help with. I've checked the related questions in SO and none give an answer to this particular question that I can find.

**Background**

We have an existing application which fetches data from an API (in the background thread) and then saves the records returned into core data. We also need to display these records in the application at the time.

So the process we currently go through is to:

1. Make a network request for data (background)
2. Parse the data and map the objects to NSManagedObjects and save (background)
3. In the completion handler (main thread) we fetch records from core data with the same order and limit that we requested from the API.

Most tutorials on core data concurrency follow this pattern of saving in one thread and then fetching in another, but most of them give examples like:

```
NSArray *listOfPeople = ...;
[NSManagedObjectHelper saveDataInBackgroundWithContext:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext){
    for (NSDictionary *personInfo in listOfPeople)
    {
        PersonEntity *person = [PersonEntity createInContext:localContext];
        [person setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:personInfo];
    }
} completion:^{
    self.people = [PersonEntity findAll];
}];
```

[Source](http://www.cimgf.com/2011/05/04/core-data-and-threads-without-the-headache/)

So regardless of the amount of records you get back, you just fetch all content. This works for small datasets, but I want to be more efficient. I've read many times not to read/write data across threads, so fetching afterwards gets around this issue, but I don't want to fetch all, I just want the new records.

**My Problem**

So, for my real world example. I want to make a request to my API for the latest information (maybe anything older than my oldest record in core data) and save it, them I need the exact data returned from the API in the main thread ready for display.

So my question is, When I reach my completion handler, how do I know what to fetch? or what did the API return?. A couple of methods I've considered so far:

1. after saving each record, store the ID in a temporary array and then perform some fetch where id IN array_of_ids.
2. If I am asking for the latest records, I could just use the count of records returned, then use an order by and limit in my request to the latest x records.

**My Question**

I realize that the above could be answering my own question but I want to know if there is a better way, or is one of those methods much better to use than the other? I just have this feeling that I am missing something

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Neither answer below actually addresses the question, This is to do with fetching and saving data in the background and then using the returned data in the main thread. I know it's not a good idea to pass data between threads, so the common way around this is to fetch from core data after inserting. I want to work out the more efficient way.

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted, theres plenty of detail in the question

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [NSFetchedResultsController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller)? Instead of fetching presented objects into array, you will use fetched controller in similar fashion. Through NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate you would be notified about all the changes performed in background (rows added, removed, changed) and no manual tracking would be needed.

Comment: We are using a NSFetchedResultsController to display the content in our tables, not all of our data operations are displayed immediately though, we have things like background fetch and fetch on silent push. The question is more about a common practice of fetching content from the network and saving, both on a background thread to avoid blocking UI, but usually you want this data returned so you can highlight new content or something. so whats the best approach in this situation

Answer (score 0):

I feel You missing case with two silmultaneous API calls. Both storring ids and counting created enities wont work for that case. Consider adding timestamp property for each PersonEntity.
Assuming that Your intention is to display recently updated persons.
The calcutation of the oldest timestamp to display can look like this:

```
@property NSDate *lastViewRefreshTime;
@property NSDate *oldestEntityToDisplay;
(...)
if (self.lastViewRefreshTime.timeIntervalSinceNow < -3) {
        self.oldestEntityToDisplay = self.lastViewRefreshTime;
    }
self.lastViewRefreshTime = [NSDate date];
[self displayPersonsAddedAfter: self.oldestEntityToDisplay];
```

Now, if two API responses returns in period shorter than 3s their data will be displayed together.

Comment: The issue is not to do with making two API requests, its concurrency